# clearInterval does not stop the timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a list of values, each value has its own timer, which depends on the date when it should be deleted, after which the value is removed from the list. Opposite each value there is a button - "update", when clicked, I send the identifier of the value via ajax, and on the back side I change the time when the value should be deleted. I write the date of the value into the date attribute. I made a general timer function. And if the data is returned successfully, I try to stop the timer and start it over again, but nothing changes - the timer does not restart. How can I fix this?

```
var counter;
function startCount(dot) {
    const interv = setInterval(() => {
        const currSeconds = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);
        const deletingTime = Number(dot.data('time'));              
        const timeLeft = deletingTime - currSeconds;
        if (timeLeft < 0) return clearInterval(counter);                
        dot.siblings().html(formatTime(timeLeft));              
        var timerText = dot.siblings().html();              
        if(timerText === '00:00'){
            dot.closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
        };           
    }, 1000);
  return interv;
}         
$('.update-dots').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var deletingTime = Number($(this).data('time'));    
    var currentTime = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);;
    var liveCircle = deletingTime - currentTime;
    counter = startCount(obj);                  
});
$('.update-dots').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/update-timer',
                data: {
                'id': $(this).attr('id'), 
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                obj.attr('data-time', data);
                clearInterval(counter);
                counter = startCount(obj);          
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: `startCount` does not return anything, so `counter = startCount(obj, counter);` will have `counter = undefined`, therefore `clearInterval(counter)` doesn't do anything, either. Even if you *do* return the timer ID, `counter` is a global, so if you start more than one timer, you can only cancel the last one. Speaking of the global `counter = startCount(obj, counter);` doesn't make much sense - passing the counter you assign to. That's probably OK if you intend to cancel it immediately in `startCounter` but you're not.

Comment: @VLAZ how should I rewrite my code? Please, help

Comment: *clearInterval doesn't stop timer* - and what exactly have you done to confirm that the argument to `clearInterval(arg)` is what you expect it to be?   It clear (pun intended) that `counter` at the time of `clearInterval(count)` is not what you expected it to be, so you should be concentrating on determine what sets/clears/doesn't set `counter`.   i.e. basic debugging.

Comment: Should be: `clearInterval(interv)`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl scope issue with that (as the only change) due to where `interv` is defined

Comment: @freedomn-m how can I clear interval?

Comment: @Tom: The overall logic is a bit strange here.  You *could* solve the immediate problem of the variable scope by only using `.each()` once (because why iterate over the same collection twice?) and defining your `counter` within that loop.  Then the AJAX response handler would see the same `counter` value for which it was started and would clear the interval.  But then you immediately start *another* interval.  Why?  Do you need to ever clear that one?

Comment: you have multiple intervals you are trying to assign to a single variable...counter...you need an array of intervals instead...a map with the specific button id and its interval value...so you only clear a single one...the right one

Comment: @David the timer is started when the value is created. If the timer expires, then it is deleted. If we clicked on the update button and received updated data, then the timer starts counting again at this value, which we updated

Comment: @Ctznkane525 and how can I write correct?

Comment: use a storage mechanism that allows you store the interval PER item...like an array